# RSA Accumulator construction - how to pick the initial state?

Tags: rsa, accumulators

I read about [RSA Accumulators](https://blog.goodaudience.com/deep-dive-on-rsa-accumulators-230bc84144d9) and I wish to construct one using a programming language of my choice. For selecting modulus N, I see various implementations picking the [RSA-2048](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-2048) number. Also, as the article suggests:

> "The initial state of the RSA Accumulator is the generator sampled
>   from the group of unknown order $g$".

However I'm not sure the best concrete value I should put into my code for the initial state of the accumulator. I saw [this](https://github.com/davidlazar/accumulator/blob/master/accumulator.go) implementation using 65537, while [here](https://github.com/cambrian/accumulator/blob/master/src/group/rsa.rs) I see tests with 3 and 4096 (I'm not sure however since I'm not programming in Rust). So what's the best **concrete** value to use for the accumulator's initial state?